# I want to run daily php file with html and js content crontab

Tags: javascript, php, html, cron

I am new to this topic and I have developed a .php file, which has an html code inside, which makes a series of functions through javascript and this through ajax, executes a php code, which registers data in the database, the code works correctly, when opening the url, internally it does the whole process.
But what I want now is to schedule this code to be executed every day at a certain time, but when doing it directly with my hosting, it returns the html code and does not execute it. I also used cron-job.org and it returns the same, it returns all the html code in text format, but it does not execute the functions and others that I have in javascript and php.
I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Could you please show what you've put in your crontab? Thanks.

Comment: CRON Job runs on server while the html and javascript code runs on browser. you won't be able to run javascript and html on server side with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, create a new PHP file that contains all function calls that normally would be executed through AJAX requests. Then schedule this new PHP file in a cronjob.

You could also script the whole thing as if you were a visitor of the page through a headless browser, for example PhantomJS or Selenium. And then schedule that.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to run js on server side using php, but if your script can run on web-server you can use `CURL` to run it as a web-page. You can also run it on localhost. Set up CURL and the set cron job like this `curl https://localhost/script.php`. Another way to run script on the web-server is `wget`, something like this: `wget https://localhost/script.php`

Comment: CURL won't execute the javascript functions on his page